# Laravel 5 Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cookie' not found

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to create a cookie in laravel 5 with

```
$cookie = Cookie::make('name', 'value');
```

in controller and i want to attach to the view. But it shows the error

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cookie' not found.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: `use Cookie;`. Done.

Answer (score 18):

Most `Class not found` are usually caused my incorrect namespace:

try

```
$cookie = \Cookie::make('name', 'value');
```

or add `use Cookie;` in your class like so:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Cookie;

UserController extends Controller{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a slash before the Cookie it will work .
Like this

```
$cookie = \Cookie::make('name', 'value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cookie('cookiename','your value',time);
```